# Cron schedule not updating after run

Tags: wp-cron, cron

Cron-jobs are incredibly slow in my website.

I created this small script, outside of the Wordpress environment, just to test the response time of WP Cron:

```
<?php

//Method which does a basic curl get request
function get_data($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        //getinfo gets the data for the request
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        //output the data to get more information.
        print_r($info);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
}

get_data('http://www.example.com?wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1486419273');
```

These are the results:

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://www.example.com/?wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1486419273
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 42.822546 // Important
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_ip] => 
    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

As you can see it has an incredible load time of almost 43 seconds.

These are my Crons as reported by Crontol plugin:

[image: list of wordpress crons]

The biggest problem I see here is that the "Next run" is not updating, meaning every cron runs every time... That's probably what's making it so slow, isn't it?

How to make the "Next run" actually changes according to the cron's "Recurrence"?

Comment: PS: Even though it shows some cache crons, the cache is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/) to execute schedules without the detour via http request. Add in `crontab -e`.

```
*/30 * * * * wp cron event run --path=/path/to/wp-docroot
```

By this you wont run into maximum execution time problems which could be the reason why you schedule execution got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did it with manual crons.

I use NGINX + PHP-FPM, which makes it harder to do manual cron tasks. So I had to go with wget to achieve it.

If you use PHP-FPM and need to trigger Wordpress's cronjobs via crontab, do:

1. Login to SSH with root.
2. Run **crontab -e**
3. Add ***/30 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O /tmp/temp_crons.txt http://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron**

Where 30 is 30 minutes. It saves the cron results to temp_crons.txt

Well, it's working:

[image]

If you use Apache, just do a regular cron with **/usr/bin/php**